# In what format do I supply a BCD field for camel-sap?

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, saprfc, bcd, sapjco3

I would like to develop an interface that transfers a data record via camel-sap to an SAP function module. The data table contains a BCD field. What is the representation of the BCD field in camel-sap-format (XML)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Trixx said, a **BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) ABAP data type is mapped to a BigDecimal** in Java. This can be found in the [SAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nwpi711/7.1.1/en-US/47/13097544d921c2e10000000a114a6b/content.htm?no_cache=true). In the default XML-to-Java bindings used by JAXB, **BigDecimal is mapped to the XML Schema Type xsd:decimal**. This can be Found in the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/bind.html).

So you supply a BCD field as a `xsd:decimal` for camle-sap-format (xml).

---

Example:

You have a field called VALUE in your SAP BAPI. The field is of type CURR (BCD) and has the length 17 with 2 decimal places. Then the attribute for this field in camel-sap-format (xml) could be defined as follows:

```
<xsd:attribute name="VALUE">
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:restriction base="**xsd:decimal**">
            <totalDigits value="17"/>
            <xsd:fractionDigits value="2"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:attribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer to your question because I have not used camel-sap yet, but as far as JCo is concerned it will automatically convert any given value to a BCD type if feasible, i.e. from a String, float, double, BigDecimal or whatsoever.
The default data type mapping for an ABAP BCD type to a Java type is `java.math.BigDecimal`.

I hope this helps.